# How to use a variable name inside of liquid shortcode to render a section file in a template file for Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

**Objective:**

I want to render a Shopify `section` inside of a `template` using a variable as the section file's name. i.e.

**Example**

Template: `templates/parent.liquid`

Section: `sections/child.liquid`

Attempting to render (include) `child.liquid` inside `parent.liquid` when `variableName = 'child'`

**context:** `*child*` could be anything -- in my theme's specific use case, I'm assigning `variableName = page.handle`. If `page.handle` matches an existing product vendor AND  `sections/[page.handle].liquid` exists, I am includuing it in the page.

**WHY?** I want to avoid a hardcoded list of available section-files in lieu if this proposed progammatic approach of dynamic filenames derived from the current page.

*The following code would go inside `templates/parent.liquid`*

**this works (hardcoded quoted strings):**

BUT, I want to avoid hard-coded filenames at all costs.

`{% section 'child' %}`

**these all throw an error (any form of dynamic filename):**

`{% section variableName %}`

`{% section {{ variableName }} %}`

`{% section 'variableName' %}`

`{% section "'" + variableName + "'" %}`

`{% section variableName %}`

`{% section "{{ variableName }}" %}`

`{% section [variableName] %}`

****edit** more errors**

`{% render variableName %}` Syntax error in tag 'render' - Template name must be a quoted string

`{% include variableName %}` look for a snippet, not a section

`{% include sections.variableName %}` Liquid error: Argument error in tag 'include' - Illegal template name

`{% include sections.[variableName] %}` Liquid error: Argument error in tag 'include' - Illegal template name

**Research**
The closest article I've found via Google is https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Dynamic-Liquid-Variable-inside-Liquid-tag/td-p/162451

**Pseudo Answer**
I'm searching for a working solution along the lines of:

`{% include sections.[page.handle] %}`

Comment: Not possible according to Shopify documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Use `include` or `render`

passing variable to `section` is not possible

[Question asked here](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Pass-variable-to-a-section-tag-section-the-variable/td-p/479854)

[Document](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/sections)

> Variables created outside sections are not available within sections.
> Likewise, variables created in sections are not available outside
> sections. If a section includes a snippet, the snippet has access to
> the variables in the section.

using variable as a filename will not work for `render`. It only works for `include`

For Example

```
 {% assign fileName = "product-" | append: product.handle %}
 {% capture productLinkContent %}
   {% include fileName %}
 {% endcapture %}
 
 {% unless productLinkContent contains "Liquid error: Could not find asset " %}
     {% include fileName %}
     
 {% else %}
     do something else
 {% endunless %}
```

so, In your `template/parent.liquid`  call `{% section 'parent-template' %}`

and in `parent-template.liquid` use `include` like above.

The reason is that you need to make sure that the `section` files exist so that it does not break shopify customizer, and there is no way to check that using liquid code right now.

Here is another solution if you really want to stick with the variable solution, is that you pass the file with `if-else` / `case - when` statement;

```
 {% assign fileName = "product-" | append: product.handle %}
 
 {% case fileName %}
 {% when 'product-a' %}
  {% section 'product-a' %}
  {% when 'product-b' %}
  {% section 'product-b' %}
  {% else %}
  do something else
 {% endcase %}
```

Comment: Thanks -- close, but I don't want to pass a variable to a section. I want to use a variable as the section's filename as the argument to "include" or "reference". I have updated my question to show errors for both of these methods.

Comment: `variableName` is a variable, {% section variableName %} is passing a variable to section.  What is the reason why you want to have section as a variable?  The correct way to create theme is to insert a specific section into template. In section, you can `render` or `include` with variable as you need.  Updated my answer

Comment: user can also choose dynamic section, which defeat the purpose of having a variable to choose a section.  Let's say that I have all these sections that a user can choose in the customizer, the job is to list them all and let the user choose, instead of us make the choice for the users.  How the section behave is different, that is achieved with `include` and `render`

Comment: one more thing, `include` and `render` will import files in the `snippets` folder, `section` will import file  from the `sections` folder.  `template` folder is called from shopify, basically, the url and admin selection. So, `{% include 'sectionFileInSectionFolder' %}` will not work

Comment: I'm trying to refactor a hard-coded IF/ELSE (like you have created) into a programmatic approach (like I'm asking about). 

The end game is to create a page and have it automagically include a sections-file (if it exists) without having to edit the liquid.

Like, I have one page template that could include 1-of-many different sections-files depending on the current page's handle, so I need something like ````{% render sections.[page.handle] %}````

Comment: Sorry to tell you that it is not possible in section

Comment: That's also the answer I keep coming to -- I appreciate your help.